# How to stop core web vitals failing - nuxt 3

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

Nuxt 3 website core web vitals have taken a dramatic turn for the worse.

GSC shows the issue as a CLS issue - however, we cannot see the immediate culprit and have tried a few things making no difference.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SedSG.png)

Our developer has tried many things, but we are stuck on what to try next. Does anyone have any ideas? Our website is: https://www.trusted-psychics.co.uk/

Everything was running fine up until the 2nd of May.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLU0K.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVM5Y.png)

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.